# sstpc with EAP-MSCHAP-v2 no suitable secret found

Tags: linux, vpn

Am trying to connect to a vpn with sstpc with EAP-MSCHAP-v2 authentication.
Found a patch for pppd that allows for mschap-v2.

My problem is with with EAP.

```
pon xyz
/usr/sbin/pppd: The remote system (xyz) is required to authenticate itself
/usr/sbin/pppd: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.
```

etc/ppp/peers/xyz

```
remotename      xyz
linkname        xyz
ipparam         xyz
pty             "sstpc --ipparam xyz --log-level 4 --nolaunchpppd xyz"
name             tvogel    
plugin          sstp-pppd-plugin.so
sstp-sock       /var/run/sstpc/sstpc-work
usepeerdns
auth
lock
require-mschap-v2
require-eap
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
```

chap-secrets and pap-secrets

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client    server    secret            IP addresses
my_username xyz "my_password" *
```

any help would be much appreciated